# Clicking on label in checkboxgroup does not stick in bootstrap for xpages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, lotus-domino

I have an xpage with bootstrap and it has a checkboxgroup with full page refresh. It is ext lib 901v00_14. When I click on square the checkmark "sticks" but when I click on the label it does not. This is a demo page that does not work, the layout is Responsive Bootstrap Configuration and the theme is Bootstrap3.2.0:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xp:label value="this is not really working" id="label1" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:label>
        <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1"
            value="#{sessionScope.itemvalues}">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="item1" itemValue="item1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="item2" itemValue="item2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="item3" itemValue="item3"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
            </xp:eventHandler></xp:checkBoxGroup>
        <xp:button value="Label" id="button1"></xp:button>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration></xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout></xp:view>
```

tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib gives

```
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   Framework is launched.
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   id State       Bundle
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   14 <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_9.0.1.v00_10_20141105-0922
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   15 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   18 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_9.0.1.v00_10_20141105-0922
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   19 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   21 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   24 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   25 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_9.0.1.v00_10_20141105-0922
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   26 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   30 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   31 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_14_20150831-1301
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   209 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   210 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   211 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   212 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   213 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
[0A74:0002-0634] 2015-09-04 14:55:59   214 INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
```

If I use oneui or not refresh it works but that is not a good solution. I did found that something similar was a problem with  901v00_10 but I thought it was resolved. 
I have used a http-proxy and the field is not sent to the server so I guess it is some sort of client issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround (suggested by the always brilliant [Tomas Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167687/thomas-adrian)) I had to set the property "disableTheme" to true for the checkboxgroup. It will require a bit of extra styling but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've logged this bug as **SPR #BGLNA28C8E**. There was a similar-ish issue before, **SPR #LHEY9QHH58**, that was fixed in release 11 of the 901 Extension Library. The problem above is slightly different. Thanks for bringing it up though, and hopefully we can find a fix for it in an upcoming release of the ExtLib.